# Confidence interval for a binomially distributed observation with few trials?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

If there are few trials and you want to get the confidence interval of a binomially distributed observation, is it still okay to use the normal approximation interval, or is that only accurate for a large n (following central limit theorem)?

If it's not accurate, how else can the confidence interval determined when the sample is small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small sample sizes, usually the Clopper-Pearson exact CI is appropriate, although it should be emphasized that it will frequently have a coverage probability well in excess of the desired confidence level.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval